# How to find failed inserts while writing to Bigtable using dataflow jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I am writing a pipeline to migrate data from GCS to Bigtable. Data is in json format. Pipeline works fine but number of records written by dataflow job and Count I get from BigQuery using BigTable as external table doesn't match.

I have set `"onlyReadLatest": false` to get all records when I read from BigQuery.

**EDIT**
Issue was with data. The json values which I was using to create row-key was creating duplicates row-keys. To verify that I added UUID in row key. Now count is matching

```
        CloudBigtableTableConfiguration bigtableTableConfig =
                new CloudBigtableTableConfiguration.Builder()
                .withProjectId(options.getBigtableProjectId())
                    .withInstanceId(options.getBigtableInstanceId())
                .withTableId(options.getBigtableTableId())
                    .build();       
PDone tableRows = btRow.get(successTag)
            .apply("WriteToBT", CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable(bigtableTableConfig));
```

Query I am using to get count on BigQuery.

```
SELECT rowkey,   
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(common.id.cell)), "") AS Id,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(common.timestamp_col.cell)), "") AS timestamp_col
FROM `<table_id>`
```

[Count using above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIsLw.png)
[Count of mutations from Dataflow job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8pQC.png)

I got to know in BigQuery we can handle failed inserts using `.withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.retryTransientErrors())`

Is any equivalent present for BigTable? If not how I can handle failed inserts?

Comment: I think there is no equivalent with `BigTable`, but you can catch errors before to call the output to `BigTable` with a dead letter queue. If you are interested on this solution, I can add an answer to show you an example.

Comment: Hi @MazlumTosun, I handled that scenario. The problem I face while writing to BigTable